# Equation of an r-braid knot

Tags: knot-theory

In N H Kuiper's paper "[A New Knot Invariant](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01458068.pdf)" he says that any circular r-braid knot can be given by for $\epsilon>0$ $$\gamma_{\epsilon}:(cos(rt)(1+\epsilon \lambda_1(t)),sin(rt)(1+\epsilon \lambda_1(t)),cos^2(rt)+\epsilon \lambda_2(t)) $$ where the function is periodic in t modulo 2$\pi$ and $\lambda_1^2+\lambda_2^2\leq 1$.

How to prove the existence of such an equation? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "existence of equation" ? This equation "exists" in itself ... Do you mean the existence of the  $\lambda_k$s ?

Comment: @JeanMarie What I meant is the existence of such an equation which parametrizes any r-braid knot.